# Fetching dynamic content from the microsoft website using powershell

Tags: powershell, request, webrequest

I'm trying to fetch the content from the microsoft webpage using powershell. link of the link is below - `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?products=windows`.

the main target is to take out the available link of "Windows Server 2022" the ahref tag from result window using powershell.

using `invoke-webrequest` helps but only fetch footer and header. trying to fetch the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

The results on that page are called and loaded after the page has finished loading using an asynchronous call to a search service.

After looking at DevTools (F12) I can see which call to use:
[image]

Armed with this information it is quite easy to run the same search in PowerShell:

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://learn.microsoft.com/api/contentbrowser/search/lifecycles?locale=en-us&facet=products&%24filter=((products%2Fany(t%3A%20t%20eq%20%27windows%27)))&%24orderBy=start%20desc&%24top=10").results | Where-Object { $_.title -eq "Windows Server 2022" }
```

The response is:
[image]

You might have to add the leading `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/` to the `url` property since that is not included in the response payload.

Comment: Hi @stinkyfriend. Thanks for your answers. also could we fetch the service pack as well. like End of lifecycle of every service pack of particular SQL Server?. for example SQL server 2014

Comment: Hi @scode123 I think you will need to see if you can do those queries in the UI and then if you figure it out then go through the same process I described above.